# Is there a way to completely disconnect an App from iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, icloud

My App can work with or without iCloud support.

If a user connects a device to iCloud and then wants to disconnect it, it's pretty easy for me to copy all data back to the local sandbox and stop using iCloud, and this device won't contribute anything new to iCloud anymore. However, changes from other devices will still be received (although not handled) on this device.

Is there a way to completely disconnect the device from iCloud, so that new changes won't be received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iCloud stores data in a folder called "Mobile Documents." Your app's container resides in this folder. iOS devices know about new files and changes immediately. However, they do not actually download the file until the app specifically requests it. Here's an example scenario:

Someone is running your app on their iPhone and their iPad. They use iCloud on both. However, on their iPhone they disable your app's iCloud but leave their iCloud account active. This means that their device always knows about changes. But since your app never requests those documents, they are never downloaded to the device and therefore do not take up space. Also, iOS will automatically remove the local copy of an iCloud file to free up space if necessary.

For more information, see developer.apple.com/icloud, specifically the videos on how to use iCloud.

Comment: Thanks, but "their device always knows about changes" means that there is still some network traffic and some space taken on the device, even though the documents are not loaded (what happens with Core Data log files? Does the App still gets metatada about them?) What I'm looking for is a way to COMPLETELY disconnect an App from iCloud on a device, so that there will be NO network traffic and NO space on the device (in other words, no subfolder for this App under Mobile Documents). Is this possible?

Comment: No. iCloud is enabled or disabled per-device, not per-app. The only way to completely stop sync traffic is for the user to remove their iCloud account (or to disable Documents & Data).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply stop responding to the NSNotifications received by your app. You can either unregister your views from these notifications, or ignore them when they're received.

Comment: Thanks. I know that. But I believe that if someone wants to disconnect from iCloud, the reason may be to free some space on the device and/or to cut down on network activity. What you're suggesting (and what I'm doing right now) increases space usage (because files are duplicated, in the sandbox as well as in the iCloud folder) and network activity still occurs, even though it's smaller (one way only). What I'm looking for is a way to disconnect the device from iCloud completely, so that the iCloud folder is released and nothing keeps coming in from iCloud.